# Laptop display randomly turns black

Tags: windows-10, display

My dell laptop display randomly turns black.  Sometimes it goes for some time with no problem than it starts turning black every minute or so until it starts “blinking” and at last it’s black most of the time.
While it’s black I can still type and it will react to my input in the background.
The OS is windows 10. I reinstalled display drivers (downloaded newest drivers) and  ran some hardware tests on startup.
Any ideas how to fix this.

Thank you!

Comment: Does it do this if you let it sit in the BIOS setup? If it does, it would indicate a hardware issue.

Comment: I wasn’t that long in bios setup, but ran hardware tests right after booting prior to loading windows, no black screens during these tests (at least one hour).

Comment: Does it occur while typing?

Comment: It happens while typing and while just viewing.

Comment: Can you plug in an external monitor?  How does it behave?  I have a hotkey that swaps internal/external displays, and every time I switch it, it shows the display briefly, then it drops out again.  I replaced the inverter, but that didn't work.